# playerSelection() is not returning but its getting passed a string value? [Rock paper scissors game]

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, getelementbyid

**Hello**, i am currently revisiting a rock paper scissors game in html/css/javascript. Now i am trying to make a corresponding website where you can click the button and it logs your playerChoice in that way. Afterwards its gonna start the game and print winner, rounds etc.. *.It seems the playerSelection function is not working correctly*. The playerChoice = this.id seems to be working correctly, *but the playerSelection function is not console logging anything*. I also wonder if i need to change anything in order to take the String out of the function and compare it (see playRound function). If you happen to know something about this please let me know :)

**This is my HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>
    <p>Play against the computer. First to 5 points wins the game!</p>
    <h2>Select a Move:</h2>

    <div id="Buttons">
        <button id="ROCK">ROCK</button>
        <button id="PAPER">PAPER</button>
        <button id="SCISSORS">SCISSORS</button>
    </div>
    
    <p id="roundTxt"></p>

    <h2>Scores:</h2>

    <ul id="scoresBox">
        <h3>Player: </h3>
        <div id="SCORES_HUMAN">0</div>
        <h3>Computer: </h3> 
        <div id="SCORES_COMPUTER">0</div>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("ROCK").onclick = playerSelection;
document.getElementById("PAPER").onclick = playerSelection;
document.getElementById("SCISSORS").onclick = playerSelection;



function getComputerChoice (){
    //select Rock Paper or Scissors at random
    //return the choice
    const PICK = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * PICK.length);
    return (PICK[random]);

}

function playerSelection() {
    //prompt user for their choice
    //return the choice
    //let playerChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");
    playerChoice = this.id;
    return playerChoice;
}
console.log(playerSelection());


function game() {
    //Scoreboard
    let SCORES_HUMAN = 0;
    let SCORES_COMPUTER = 0;

    //for(let i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        playRound(playerSelection(), getComputerChoice());
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection(), getComputerChoice()));
        
    //}

    if(SCORES_HUMAN > SCORES_COMPUTER) {
        console.log("You Win!");
    } else if(SCORES_HUMAN < SCORES_COMPUTER) {
        console.log("You Lose!");
    }
    
    console.log("HUMAN: "+ SCORES_HUMAN +" COMPUTER: "+ SCORES_COMPUTER);


    function playRound(playerSelection, getComputerChoice) {
        //compare playerSelection to getComputerChoice
        //return the outcome
        if (playerSelection === "ROCK" && getComputerChoice === "Scissors") {
            SCORES_HUMAN++;
            return "You Win! Rock beats Scissors";
        } else if (playerSelection === "ROCK" && getComputerChoice === "Paper") {
            SCORES_COMPUTER++;
            return "You Lose! Paper beats Rock";
        } else if (playerSelection === "PAPER" && getComputerChoice === "Rock") {
            SCORES_HUMAN++;
            return "You Win! Paper beats Rock";
        } else if (playerSelection === "PAPER" && getComputerChoice === "Scissors") {
            SCORES_COMPUTER++;
            return "You Lose! Scissors beats Paper";
        } else if (playerSelection === "SCISSORS" && getComputerChoice === "Paper") {
            SCORES_HUMAN++;
            return "You Win! Scissors beats Paper";
        } else if (playerSelection === "SCISSORS" && getComputerChoice === "Rock") {
            SCORES_COMPUTER++;
            return "You Lose! Rock beats Scissors";
        } else {
            return "It's a tie!";
        }

    }
}

game();
```

**This is my css:**

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 50px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

button {
    border: .3rem solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin: .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .75rem .5rem;
    width: 6rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(89, 89, 89);
    text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem rgb(229, 229, 229);
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
    background-color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.208);
}


.Buttones {
    flex: display;
    align-self: center;
}
```

I appreciate any help i get and thank you for reading :)

Clicking the rock button (or paper/scissors button) will pass on the string "rock" into the playround function and the game will be played out correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting to see. Line 6 of `game()` calls `playRound()` with no arguments, and you then call it again inside a `console.log()` with the arguments? You also have mentioned that `playerSelection()` is not logging anything, but it doesn't have make a `console.log()` call

Comment: @Stitt
so after reading your comment (thanks for the fast answer btw.) i adjusted the code to:
line 24: console.log(playerSelection());
line 33:  playRound(playerSelection(), getComputerChoice());
After doing it the console.log does not do anything (if i did it correctly at least). and the other thing about the no argument playround did not change a thing as well unfortunately (maybe i made a mistake again )? I will edit the above code in the question as well to the newly added things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of issues with your code.

1. Calling `playRound()` twice:

```
playRound(playerSelection(), getComputerChoice());
console.log(playRound(playerSelection(), getComputerChoice()));
```

I understand that you're trying to see what `playRound()` is doing, but in actuality this is executing every "round" twice. You already have text statements being returned in `playRound()`, so either

- change your `return`s to `console.log()`s and just call `playRound(playerSelection(), getComputerChoice())`, **OR**
- remove the call to `playRound()` which is **not** inside the `console.log()`, and leave `playRound()` as is.

2. As mentioned by Ahmed above, you are not passing the event of the click but a reference to the function itself. You will need to listen to the event emitted when pressing the button in order to correctly process the player's selection
3. A minor point, but you mention in the html doc that the first player to 5 wins, however you only allow 5 rounds to be played with your (commented out) for-loop. Instead, use a while-loop like the one below:

```
while (SCORES_HUMAN < 5 and SCORES_COMPUTER < 5){
    playRound(playerSelection(), getComputerChoice());
}
```

**EDIT**
Updated to include working example of JS code. No associated changes to either HTML or CSS.

```
function getComputerChoice (){
    //select Rock Paper or Scissors at random
    //return the choice
    const PICK = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * PICK.length);
    return (PICK[random]);

}

let SCORES_HUMAN = 0;
let SCORES_COMPUTER = 0;

const SCORES_HUMAN_TEXT = document.getElementById("SCORES_HUMAN");
const SCORES_COMPUTER_TEXT = document.getElementById("SCORES_COMPUTER");

const ROCK = document.getElementById("ROCK");
const PAPER = document.getElementById("PAPER");
const SCISSORS = document.getElementById("SCISSORS");


function updateScores() {
  SCORES_HUMAN_TEXT.innerHTML = SCORES_HUMAN
  SCORES_COMPUTER_TEXT.innerHTML = SCORES_COMPUTER
}


ROCK.addEventListener("click", function (e){
  playRound ("ROCK");

});
PAPER.addEventListener("click", function (e){
  playRound("PAPER");

});
SCISSORS.addEventListener("click", function (e){
  playRound("SCISSORS");

});



function game() {
    //Scoreboard

    /*
    while (SCORES_HUMAN < 5 && SCORES_COMPUTER < 5){
        playRound(playerSelection(), getComputerChoice());
    }
        
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection(), getComputerChoice()));
    */    
    

    if(SCORES_HUMAN > SCORES_COMPUTER) {
        console.log("You Win!");
    } else if(SCORES_HUMAN < SCORES_COMPUTER) {
        console.log("You Lose!");
    }
    
    console.log("HUMAN: "+ SCORES_HUMAN +" COMPUTER: "+ SCORES_COMPUTER);

}

function playRound(playerSelection) {
  computerChoice = getComputerChoice()
  //compare playerSelection to getComputerChoice
  //return the outcome
  if (playerSelection === "ROCK" && computerChoice === "Scissors") {
    SCORES_HUMAN++;
    // return "You Win! Rock beats Scissors";
  } else if (playerSelection === "ROCK" && computerChoice === "Paper") {
    SCORES_COMPUTER++;
    // return "You Lose! Paper beats Rock";
  } else if (playerSelection === "PAPER" && computerChoice === "Rock") {
    SCORES_HUMAN++;
    // return "You Win! Paper beats Rock";
  } else if (playerSelection === "PAPER" && computerChoice === "Scissors") {
    SCORES_COMPUTER++;
    // return "You Lose! Scissors beats Paper";
  } else if (playerSelection === "SCISSORS" && computerChoice === "Paper") {
    SCORES_HUMAN++;
    // return "You Win! Scissors beats Paper";
  } else if (playerSelection === "SCISSORS" && computerChoice === "Rock") {
    SCORES_COMPUTER++;
    // return "You Lose! Rock beats Scissors";
  } else {
    // return "It's a tie!";
  }
  updateScores()
}


//game();
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the detailed answer!
Regarding point 2. ,i tried doing it like this: link to code image [link](https://imgur.com/a/USPrMXm)`code` . If i console log the return lines instead i get the desired output. So i thought that if i could return them up to the playerSelection i could use "ROCK","PAPER" or "SCISSORS" if clicked on as a String and therefore in the playerRound function. Part 1/2

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/fus38xid/pen/MWZeZNN?editors=1011)`codepen`
Part 2/2
I also thought about only doing it by buttons instead of element by id. For example "click",function(e){ if(button content == "ROCK){ return "Rock"}else if(button content == Paper){ return "paper" and so on. But right now im searching on how to return the id as a string value to playerselection so it can be used on playround. I might do the individual button as one function later on. As always thanks for helping and explaining!
@Stitt

Comment: Edit:
i forgot to ping you my bad sry
@Stitt

Comment: By the way the first time i tried it i had the whole thing outside of the playerSelection function like this:
[link](https://imgur.com/a/xxnFq9E) `code how it was first`

Comment: Have a look at your codepen, I have made some changes so that the basic functionality is there! If you have any questions feel free to ask, but I have left the exercise of making the game end once a player reaches 5 up to you

Comment: Hi @Stitt i dont see any changes made to the codepen would you mind sending the code here on stackoverflow?
Thank you for the support!

Comment: Have edited, take a look!

Answer (score 0):

because 'this' in playerSelection function points to the function not the event.
pass event argument to playerSelection function

```
function playerSelection(e) { ... }
```